# Is this possible in Java: Map<SomeObject, Map<SomeOtherObject>>?

Tags: java, types

Is this possible in Java: `Map<SomeObject, Map<SomeOtherObject>>`? I'm trying `Map<Integer, Map<String>>` am getting an

> "Incorrect number of arguments for
>   type Map; it cannot be
>   parameterized with arguments "

error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map` maps keys to values, so `Map<String>` is incorrect. So you'd need something like `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: sorry - brain-ache on my part: I hadn't noticed I'd omitted the second parameter!

Answer (score 4):

Every `Map` needs to be parametrized on two types; your second (nested) Map has only one.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really like that. You need to give a type for both `Key` and `Value` for the second "inner" `Map`, this is ok:

```
Map<SomeObject, Map<SomeOtherObject, Object>>
```

Just like with the outer `Map`, where the `Key` is `SomeObject`, and `Value` is the inner `Map`. So, if you add a value specification for the inner `Map` is, that would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second argument on your second `Map<>`. Perhaps you mean `Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>`?